# Install two web sites in two different virtual directories with a Visual Studio Web Setup project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, installation, web-setup-project, webdeploy

I'm trying to put two web projects that needs to be installed in different virtual directories in the same Web Setup Project, because they are closely related, but they have to run sepparately.

I can put project 1 in one directory, and project 2 in a subdirectory in the same virtual directory.

I've tried to add a "Web custom folder" in the filesystem editor, and configure one of the outputs to go there, then when I run the installer, the textbox for the virtual directory appears empty, and after put some the installation fails.

Can this be done? How?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it. What you described here just works: One additional Web Custom Folder for each additional virtual directory and add output of the target project to each one. Make sure that the property of each of the folders is different from TARGETDIR and is all capitalized (global variable). They will have to share the same AppPool by default, though.